# Customised Sonar Qube Analysis Report

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to generate customized analysis reports from sonar. I am using sonar-ws-client. My code is :

```
    Sonar sonar = new Sonar(new HttpClient4Connector(new Host(url, login, password)));

    Resource JunitTestCaseExample = sonar.find(ResourceQuery.createForMetrics("JunitTestCaseExample:JunitTestCaseExample", "critical_violations", 
            "major_violations", "minor_violations", "info_violations", "tests", "blocker_violations", "statements","coverage","uncovered_lines","lines",
            "skipped_tests","test_failures", "test_errors", "test_success_density", "new_coverage","overall_coverage"));

    Measure statements = JunitTestCaseExample.getMeasure("statements");
    System.out.println("statements : " + statements.getMetricKey() + " === " + statements.getFormattedValue());
    System.out.println(statements.getVariation1());
```

I am able to get most of the values, but  `statements.getVariation1()` always returns `null`.
Is there any way to get the variation Value on Measure for 7 Days, 15 Days and 30 Days?

Comment: Thanks to not duplicate questions : http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Customised-Sonar-Qube-Analysis-Report-td5024916.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a standard but you can fetch required data from sonar Db as its not available through web service Customised Sonar Qube Analysis Report.

Step 1-
fetch period_param from snapshots with the help of project_id
from this you can manage to get variation period as you mention in your question

2)-Execute this query,It will give you all variations, after that you can put your logic to pick what you want
select distinct proj.name NAME_OF_PROJ,metric.name metric_name, metric.description Description, projdesc.value value,projdesc.variation_value_1,projdesc.variation_value_2,projdesc.variation_value_3,projdesc.variation_value_4,projdesc.variation_value_5 ,snap.created_at CREATED_DATE from projects proj inner join snapshots snap on snap.project_id=proj.id inner join " + "(select max(snap2.id) as id from snapshots snap2 where snap2.project_id  in ("+projectId+") GROUP BY snap2.project_id ) as Lookup on Lookup.id=snap.id inner join project_measures projdesc on projdesc.snapshot_id=snap.id inner join metrics metric on  projdesc.metric_id =metric.id where  metric.id between '1' and "+metric_id_Count+'

Hope it helps you.
Again remember as mention on sonar group its not a standard.

Comment: Hey Amit, Thank you very much for your help. Its working as per my need.

Comment: Hey Kuldeep,If you want for information you can check my blog   http://pathakamit783.blogspot.in/2014/05/get-data-variation-of-sonar-to-create.html